# problemas con posicionamiento de texto en un input

Tags: html, css, html5, css3

Hola buenas tengo una pequeña consulta, lo que pasa es que estoy haciendo un input pero mas alto de lo normal debido a que es para mensajes pero al momento de agregarle height a este el texto va quedando en medio en vez de comenzar arriba a la izquierda como es habitual, me gustaría saber si hay alguna manera de subir el texto o algo por el estilo, ya probé con text aling pero nada,
adjunto foto el problema
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

les adjunto mi codigo tambien:

```
 <p>
  <label class="Mensaje" for="Mensaje">Mensaje
       <span class="obligatorio">*</span>
  </label>
  <input type="text" class="input_Mensaje" name="mensaje" id="message" required="message">
 </p>
```

codigo css:

```
input {
    background-color: #fbfbfb;
    width: 88%;
    height: 250px;
    border-radius: 5px;
    border-style: solid;
    border-width: 1px;
    margin-top: 10px;
    padding-left: 10px;
    margin-bottom: 20px;
}
```

Comment: No es mejor usar una etiqueta textarea? si usarás eso pondrias los atributos rows y cols y no tendrias problema con el cursor del mouse

Comment: Tengo entendido que la etiqueta input solo puede contener una linea. La etiqueta textarea puede contener varias lineas

Comment: El problema es que estas usando demasiado ancho y altura `width: 88%; height: 250px` Además te recomiendo que uses mejor la etiqueta `<textarea></textarea>`

Comment: hola, si tenia text area pero a esa se le puede ajustar el tamaño y necesito que sea fijo, pero al ser fijo se le quita lo responsive, por eso la deseche

Answer (score 2):

hola para lo que intentas hacer es recomendable usar un textarea de la siguiente forma:

```
 <p>
  <label class="Mensaje" for="Mensaje">Diagnostico clinico
   <span class="obligatorio">(*)</span>
  </label>
  <textarea class="form-control resize-textarea" name="mensaje" id="message" 
  required="message"></textarea>
 </p>
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

el elemento textarea es util cuando quieres agregar muchos mas caracteres que normalmente agregarias en un input type text, aca en dejo documentacion acerca de la etiqueta textarea [Etiqueta HTML textarea](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/HTML/Element/textarea)

Puedes evitar que un textarea se agrande por el usuario de la siguiente forma:

```
.resize-textarea{
 resize:none;
}
```

Creas una clase en el css, se la agregas a tu textarea para que no se pueda cambiar las dimensiones

Comment: Muchísimas gracias te pasaste

Answer (score 0):

la solución es mejor un textArea y el tamaño se configura en sus atributos rows="" cols=""

```
           <div class="col-lg-12">
            
            <div class="form-group has-success">
              <textarea  class="form-control" rows="3" cols="75"  id="descripcion" name="descripcion" placeholder="Describa que es lo que necesita?" required ></textarea>                
            </div>
          </div>
```